# Silverlight. Hide control

Tags: silverlight, user-controls

I have silverlight application. He is exist several SL dll's, who exist some list of controls. And in toolbox I see all my user controls. Its not so good, because some controls was added for help main controls display data.

Can I set some property/class extension/someone else to hide controls? I used him just inside my dll.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was also answered here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1424776/1308645

Just add the `[ToolboxItem(false)]` attribute to the classes that you don't want to show in the ToolBox.

```
[ToolboxItem(false)]
public class HelperControl : UserControl 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks! Its solve just one part of problem. When i use dll, in his metadata I see this controls too. And, for example, in IntelliScience view I see all controls, what i need, and others

Comment: Hi, in IntelliSense you will see all `public` members. If you are viewing IntelliSense from within the same project, you will also see `private` and `protected` members. If you are sure you don't want to access those members from outside the assembly, you can mark them as `private` or even `internal', but doing so now (afterwards) could break things for other people that are also using the assembly.

Comment: This not working, because if you change public modifier to private in control code behind, VS don't build this project - control class not can be private, protected or internal